# C# Reading Decimal Value From Registry

Tags: c#, registry

i have a NumericUpDown control and want to update its contents from the registry. So far this is what i got:

```
this.apTime.Value = APRegsitry.GetValue("apTime").ToString();
```

Obviously that wont work so how do i set this.apTime to the value of the registry key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what the issue is.  Are you having problems converting it to a decimal?  If so try Decimal.Parse

```
Object obj = APRegistry.GetValue("apTime");
String str = obj != null ? obj.ToString() : "0";
Decimal value = Decimal.Parse(str);
this.apTime.Value = value;
```

If not can you elaborate further as to what the problem is?

**EDIT** Updated code to account for null return from GetValue

Comment: Decimal value = Decimal.Parse(APRegistry.GetValue("apTime").ToString());

You forgot to add the Decimal.Parse.  :)

Also you can try Convert.ToDecimal(stringValue);

Comment: @Chris, It's embarassing to forget the line your entire answer is based around.  Thanks!

Comment: i keep getting "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in program.exe" with both decimal.parse and convert.todecimal

Comment: wait.. o keep getting that because the key didnt exist :S it works now thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't trust the value from the registry since a user can edit it outside your application. You need to handle the following cases:

- registry key doesn't exist
- registry key exists, but name/value doesn't exist (`null`)
- you expect a `string`, value is not `string` type (e.g. it is an `int` or `byte[]`)
- value is a `string` but not parsable to `decimal` (`""`, `"abc"`)

If the key doesn't exist, `RegistryKey.OpenSubKey(name)` returns null. You might want to handle that and create the key. If the key exists, but not the name/value pair, then `RegistryKey.GetValue(name)` returns null. You can handle that by passing a default value to the overload `RegistryKey.GetValue(name, defaultValue)` or by using `??`.

Now, if the name/value pair exists but has an invalid value (`""`, `"abc"`), you'll get an exception from `Parse()`. The `Parse()` methods (in `int`, `decimal`, `DateTime`, etc) have been pretty much been deprecated by `TryParse()`. They return `false` instead of throwing `FormatException`.

```
// passing the default value to GetValue()
object regValue = APRegistry.GetValue("apTime", "0");
// ...same as...
object regValue = APRegistry.GetValue("apTime") ?? "0";

decimal value;

// regValue will never be null here, so safe to use ToString()
if(decimal.TryParse(regValue.ToString(), out value))
{
    this.apTime.Value = value;
}
else
{
    // Name/pair does not exist, is empty,
    // or has invalid value (can't parse as decimal).

    // Handle this case, possibly setting a default value like this:
    this.apTime.Value = 0; 
}
```